# Pass folder name via URL to SPO Rest API call in Custom ASPX page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sharepoint-online, rest

I have one page listing different folder URLs. Clicking the link should trigger the code below on the second page using parameters passed from the URL from page one.

I am trying to pass Folder name parameter via URL to load the `API` call in custom `ASPX` page on `SPO`. The URL linking to this second page code below will have the folder details.

URL format from page one - `<<<SPO_SITE>>>/teams/<<<SPO_TENANT>>>/SiteAssets/Image.aspx?Folder="<<<FOLDER_NAME>>>"`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
           var requestUri = "<<<SPO_SITE>>>/teams/<<<SPO_TENANT>>>/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<<<SPO_DOC_LIB>>>/<<<FOLDER>>>')/Files?$top=2000&$select=ServerRelativeUrl";
              $.ajax({
                 url: requestUri,
                 type: "GET",
                 headers: {
                     "accept":"application/json; odata=verbose"
                 },
                 success: onSuccess,
   });
   
     function onSuccess(data) {
        var objItems = data.d.results;
   
        var divContent = '<div class="row" id="myList">';
        for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
   
            divContent += '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="<<<SPO_SITE>>>/' + objItems[i].ServerRelativeUrl + '"><a class="stretched-link" target="_blank" href="<<<SPO_SITE>>>/' + objItems[i].ServerRelativeUrl + '"></a></div></div>';
   
    }
      $('#ImgGrid').append(divContent);
      }
   });
</script>
<main role="main">
   <section class="pt-4 pb-4 text-center">
      <div class="container">


      </div>
   </section>
   <div class="container">
      <div id="myList">
         <div id="ImgGrid"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>

<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Kindly review the code and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images is in the url like this:

https://Tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SPO_DOC_LIB/FOLDER

Then in getfolderbyserverrelativeurl please pass the relative url like this:

/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/sitename/<<<SPO_DOC_LIB>>>/<<>>')/Files?$top=2000&$select=ServerRelativeUrl

Update with completed code snippet:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.6.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
        var relativeurl = "/sites/dev/Share Documents/" + GetParameterValues("Folder");
        var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('"+relativeurl+"')/Files?$top=2000&$select=ServerRelativeUrl";
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: onSuccess,
        });


        });

        function onSuccess(data) {
            var objItems = data.d.results;
            console.log(objItems);
            var divContent = '<div class="row" id="myList">';
            for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {

                divContent += '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"><img src="' + objItems[i].ServerRelativeUrl + '"><a class="stretched-link" target="_blank" href="' + objItems[i].ServerRelativeUrl + '"></a></div></div>';

            }
            $('#ImgGrid').append(divContent);
        }

        function GetParameterValues(param) {
            var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
                var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
                if (urlparam[0] == param) {
                    return urlparam[1];
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

<main role="main">
    <section class="pt-4 pb-4 text-center">
        <div class="container">


        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="myList">
            <div id="ImgGrid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the code demo above, My site url is https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/

So the relative url is using /sites/dev/Shared Documents/folder1

Update:

Get Folder querystring parameter in the url like this in the second page:

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["Folder"];
```

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion. I am new to this and i do not know to pass this value from the url to the api call. Kindly amend my code if possible.

Comment: @JacksonChristopher, Check the updated answer.

Comment: Appreciate your assistance, to clarify, I have one page which provides a url to generate this second page using values from url delivered from first page. This second page code will be a generic page that receives the input and updates the API call using URL parameter and renders. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Original post explained.

Comment: If you want to get the ?Folder querystring in this url, use the function in this blog : https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/get-query-string-value-in-jquery-sharepoint/, I will update in the answer above.

Comment: Would love it if you could give me a javascript function that takes the Folder name from the incoming URL and rewrites the API call and renders the snippet.

Comment: Seems you are looking for this function:

https://www.spguides.com/how-to-retrieve-query-string-value-using-jquery-in-sharepoint-online/

You can call the function to get the folder name and pass into Rest API call.

Comment: Thankyou Jerry, since Im new to JS, im having a tough time writing the function to receive the url value and pass it to the apl call randomly on each page load using different variable.

Comment: You just need to get the folder name by calling function like this:

var folder = GetParameterValues('Folder');

function itself don't need modify any more, you can use it directly.

Comment: Modify into answer, please check it. Hopefully, it will be helpful to  you so that you can get some idea.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thankyou!